# synchronizing several goroutines with channels carrying the amqp message

Tags: go

I'm a bit of a loss why the following design is creating a memory leak. Able to repro the leak via a simple `kubectl top pod` command and watching memory hit the roof after a few seconds of execution.

I have a worker which watches a RabbitMQ message queue for messages.  If I drop ~100K of small messages (each ~200B) into the exchange, I'm seeing the following GO app start to leak.

Before rewriting, I have the time and energy to deep dive and understand what exactly is causing the memory leak.

```
type workerMessage struct {
    AmqpMessage amqp.Delivery
    Data        types.Data
}


func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < opts.WorkerCount; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go w.StartWork(&wg)
    }

    // create a wait group with 1 routine added
    var wait sync.WaitGroup
    wait.Add(1)

    // capture 2 signals, and have them send to signalChan
    stopChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(stopChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, os.Kill, os.Interrupt)

    // wait for a receive on the signal channel, and decrement the wait group
    // when a singal is received
    go func() {
        <-stopChan
        wait.Done()
    }()

    // block until a signal is received
    wait.Wait()

}

func (w *Worker) StartWork(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()


    // messages will be acked from AMQP here
    chToBeAcked := make(chan workerMessage)
    go w.watchForAMQPMessagesToAck(&iwg, chToBeAcked)

    // data will be written to cassandra or object storage
    chDataToStorage := make(chan workerMessage)
    go w.writeDataToStorage(&iwg, chDataToStorage, chToBeAcked)

    // call services, process data and decides what to do next
    chProcessData := make(chan workerMessage)
    go w.ProcessData(&iwg, chProcessData, chDataToStorage, chToBeAcked)

    messageChannel, err := amqpChannel.Consume(
        queue.Name,
        ....
    )

    stopChan := make(chan bool)
    go func() {

        for message := range messageChannel {
            wm := workerMessage{
                AmqpMessage: message,
            }
            chProcessData <- wm
        }
    }()
    <-stopChan
}

func (w *Worker) ProcessData(
    wg *sync.WaitGroup,
    chProcessData <-chan workerMessage,
    chDataToStorage chan workerMessage,
    chMessagesWaitingForAck chan workerMessage,
    ){
    defer wg.Done()
    for msg := range chProcessData {
        ...
        make some API calls
        update some things in msg.Data
        ...

        If fastExit {
            chMessagesWaitingForAck <- msg
        } else {
            chDataToStorage <- msg
        }
    }
}

func (w *Worker) writeDataToStorage(
    wg *sync.WaitGroup,
    chDataToStorage <-chan workerMessage,
    chMessagesWaitingForAck chan workerMessage,
    ){
    defer wg.Done()
    for msg := range chDataToStorage {
        ...
        write data to cassandra or key/val object storage
        ...
        chMessagesWaitingForAck <- msg
    }
}

func (w *Worker) watchForAMQPMessagesToAck(
    wg *sync.WaitGroup,
    chMessagesWaitingForAck <-chan workerMessage,
){
    defer wg.Done()
    for msg := range chMessagesWaitingForAck {
        err := msg.AmqpMessage.Ack(false)
        w.stopOnError("failed to ack a message", msg, err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program quits immediately: nothing prevents `main` from returning. It looks you've simplified your code to the point where it's too much different to what you actually have.

Comment: @zerkms i've specifically removed the majority of the meat from main().  i assure you, the workers do finish their work.    memory consumption is left behind however

Comment: "i assure you" --- your current code doesn't represent the problem you asked about.

Comment: @zerkms I will fill out the main loop back in.   however, if you can skim through and see why this would consume so much memory after running through ~100K records, let me know

Comment: I skimmed through and I see no `wg.Wait()` anywhere in your code. Your currently posted code makes very little sense. Not sure how it's helpful to post irrelevant code.

Comment: Have you tried to mem-profile your *actual* code?

Comment: @zerkms take a look at the `StartWork` function and on.  i've udpated the main function for your readability

Comment: Is there a place where you wait for iwg workgroup to be done? You keep adding to it, but I don't see a iwg.Wait()

Comment: if i do `iwg.Wait()` then it will block.  i've gone ahead and removed all wait groups ... and its still leaking ram.   These goroutines arent equal, so the sync group doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

The problem was creating the goroutines for every message!  Pure oversight due to lack of sleep

Updating my question so nobody makes the same mistake

Comment: If you handle it properly - 1 goroutine per message should not cause a memory _leak_